# Memory Address as Hash in HashTable. Why can't HasTable use actual memory address of the Key as Hash?

Tags: java, hash, hashtable, bucket

May be this is a basic question or a basic idea behind this.

Why can't HasTable use actual memory address of the Key as Hash? Or Hash the address of the key and use it?

I saw some posts saying the default `hashCode()` of the key (object) is actually the Memory address of the object, which I think is not correct.

And I read in a post that says, the bucket address is actually `hash % number of existing buckets`? This is not correct either.

Can someone clarify?

Comment: Java doesn't provide access to the memory address of any objects

Comment: @MadProgrammer True, and there are good reasons for it (outside the scope of this question), but I presume it could always be added (with small effort too) if it was useful. It isn't, but that's stuff for an answer.

Comment: @delnan The main reason why Java doesn't give access to the memory address of Objects was to try a prevent all the issues that languages like C & C++ have with memory arithmetic and manipulation (accidental or otherwise).  I don't ever see it being added.  Therefore, they only (real) way to tell the difference between two objects is through the `equals` and `hashcode` methods

Comment: @MadProgrammer Exposing the numeric value of the address would be all that's needed (for this purpose). Nobody talks about adding pointers and pointer arithmetic (well, arguably references are pointers without pointer arithmetic, but that's really off topic here).

Comment: @MadProgrammer you can probably get it with The Unsafe.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Or `==` and [`System.identityhashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: The actual memory address in Java can change (eg by a compacting garbage collector, the young/new garbage collector etc)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel.. As the objects are moved around in generational collectors, it makes sense not to use actual address because the memory location changes which fails the contract of hashcode that it should be consistent within a single run of application. But these so called generations are introduced in 1.2-1.3, but hashcode method was there in the Object class since the beginning. So y do u think they didn't use memory address at that time :) ? ofcourse, the default Object's impl is done my mapping it to actual address but they've overridden that in many classes like String for instance.

Comment: @Arkantos Maybe they did use it originally who knows, but I think it is largely irrelevant today to reminisce on how things might have worked in Java 1.1. And as Java is a virtual machine that is supposed to hide these kind of implementation details, I think it is the wrong path to walk.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a class does not override `hashCode()`, and just inherits the default implementation from `java.lang.Object`, then in a typical JVM, its `hashCode()`, really will be, more or less, an internal pointer to it. (Obviously that's not the whole story, because the return-type of `hashCode()` is `int`, which wouldn't accommodate 64-bit JVMs; and these aren't real pointers to physical memory locations, firstly because the OS handles the mapping from virtual addresses to physical ones, and secondly because, even if the JVM handled that, garbage-collectors can move an object from one heap to another without affecting its `hashCode()`. But still, "internal memory address" is a good first approximation.)

The reason that most JDK classes override `hashCode()` is that we always want `hashCode()` to be "compatible" with `equals()`; that is, if `a.equals(b)`, then we want `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()`. (This makes sense when you consider that you generally don't want — for example — a `Map<String, Object>` to have two different `"abc"` entries just because the keys are two different `String` instances. And generally you'd want to be able to look up an entry by typing `map.get("abc")`, rather than needing to have the original instance of the key handy. If two keys are equal, then we usually want them to be treated as equal.)

If you really want pointer-equality in your map, you can use [the `java.util.IdentityHashMap` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html).

Answer (score 3):

The default `Object.hashCode()` is not strictly a memory address, but unless you have a huge memory, it's indeed unique among all the objects in the JVM, so you could see it as a "logical" address.

A HashMap has a limited number of buckets, and each key is indeed assigned a bucket based on its hash code. There is not one bucket per hash code. So even if two objects have a different hash code, they could end up in the same bucket. That's why it's important to have hashCode as well distributed as possible, to avoid such collisions.

Using the system identity hash code of a key (i.e. the hash code returned by `Object.hashCode()`) is not desirable most of the time, because you want two keys to be equal if they hold the same information, not if they are the same object instance. For example, if you store a student in a map based on his SSN, and later get the SSN of this student from some web service or from the database, you won't have the same STring instance, but you want to be able to find the student in the map using the SSN you received.

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't HashTable use actual memory address of the Key as Hash?

Because key equality matters. When two objects are "equal" (`one.equals(two)` returns true), the hash codes must also be equal (`one.hashCode() == two.hashCode()`).

Answer (score 1):

The default `hashCode()` is *not* the memory address, it's a the "identity hash".

The memory address may change, but the identity is constant for a given instance.

Comment: In the same vein, an identity hash can be shared by multiple objects, but the address must be unique to an object (at a given point in time).

Answer (score 0):

You can have any implementation of hashCode that you feel is optimum without breaking the rules laid down for hashCode and equals in the JavaSE apis.

Check equals and hashcode rules here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

This is important as the Collections library and other apis heavily rely on this properties to implement their own behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The memory address should not be used as hashCode of an object (unless its equals method performs only an identity comparison). The reason is explicitly written in its [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29):

> If two objects are equal according to the {@code equals(Object)}
>   method, then calling the {@code hashCode} method on each of the two
>   objects must produce the same integer result.

In the case the the equals method performs only an identity comparison, the memory address is enough, as both hashCode() and equals() would be only equal for the same object.

Comment: I'm sorry, how does the section you quote imply that? The `equals` method does identity comparison by default, i.e. it will only be true if both references refer to the same object (and thus the addressed would be the same).

Comment: @delnan Actually, it is possible to make two different instances of the same object equal

Comment: You're right. Therefore, memory address could only be used as hash code if its "equals" method performs an identity comparison. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @MadProgrammer It is, and then `hashCode` must be changed to maintain the quoted invariant. I referred to the *default* (i.e. the one of `Object`) `hashCode` and `equals`. Now, if the answer also gave a reason why this invariant and the ability to override the equality comparision is useful (as in ruakh's answer), it would make sense. But currently, it doesn't really address the question.